# Few questions on Makefile

Tags: makefile

**Question 1**
If you define step

```
  22 clean:
  23   rm $(OBJECTS)
```

If there any way to gracefully "*do nothing, if there is nothing to delete*"?

**Question 2**
Assume the following line, again, is there a way to gracefully exit with a warhing when no files are found when processing line

```
  6 SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.cpp)
```

**Question 3** 
How can one perform the final post processing on the final product, like `mv $(PRODUCT) someDir`? Where would this instruction be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Just use `rm -f`, which is telling `rm` to ignore it if the files are missing.

3) That can just be the last step of the target that actually builds the product, or you can create a target named `install` (for example) that depends on your build target, and then contains this `mv` command.

Answer (score 1):

Answering **question #2**:

```
SOURCES := $(or $(wildcard src/*.cpp), $(warning No source found in 'src'))
```

This will emit a warning when there are no files matching `src/*.cpp` pattern. `SOURCES` variable remains empty.

See the corresponding [chapter](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) in GNU Make manual.